# IntelliJ Idea - Is there a way to make the Structure Window view sticky

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm learning Java and our instructor recommended using IntelliJ IDEA.

I'd like to be in my file with my main class but see the structure of another class i'm working with in the structure window.  Is there a way to do this?

When i click on another class file, I see the structure, but as soon as click back into my file with main, the structure view updates to the contents of main.

If this is not the preferred way to view this, is there another similar way?

Comment: Why you would like to have the **structure** of the other class, since IntelliJ will prompt you of what you can do with the other class when using it.

Comment: My memory is not awesome and I don't remember the method and variable names of the class i wrote 30 minutes ago.  Was hoping to keep them up while I was working on a another class that was using that class.  My work around was to copy the variables and the functions into another file.  yes i know it auto prompts when you type a few characters, but I had to remember what they were called to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in IDEA. Feature request for quick File Structure View: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99339